# Return Cell address within range

Tags: excel, vba

I made a function that accepts a range as a parameter.

I am doing some calculations based on items inside the range.

I am required to return a cell's address inside this range. I am having difficulties finding the function that enables me to do this.

I would have thought I could have retrieved the cells address via Range_Name.cells(row_index,col_index).address. However this does not seem to be working.

Any advise is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: This problem is resolved. I was casting it to a string and once I got rid of the cast it enabled me to return the cells address via my method above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The row_index and col_index work within the parent range, e.g:

- ActiveSheet.Cells(1,1).Address => A1
- Range("B2:D14").Cells(1,1).Address => B2